# django social auth registration facebook email

Tags: django, facebook, django-socialauth

Hello I'd like to allow users to login/register through facebook. 
Authentication works but backend creates User instance with the combination of first and last name (from Facebook) as a username and no email.
Google oauth2 backend works just fine.

Here are my settings:

```
  FACEBOOK_APP_ID                   = 'appid'
  FACEBOOK_API_SECRET               = 'apisecret'
  FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']

  SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS          = True
  SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_RANDOM_USERNAME = False
  SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME      = 'socialauth_user'
  SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME     = 'socialauth_complete'
  SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'
  LOGIN_ERROR_URL                   = '/login/error/'
  LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL                = '/'
  SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL            = 'users.User'
  SESSION_SERIALIZER =   django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

My app should create users with email filled with data(email) from facebook.
I can't overcome this.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Facing same issue, did you got any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) (which replaces django-social-auth) you have to set these two to obtain email from FB:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
  'locale': 'pl_PL',
  'fields': 'id, name, email',
}
```

`SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE` is equivalent of `FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS`, and I guess `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS` is equivalent of `FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS`. So I would try:

```
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
  'locale': 'pl_PL',
  'fields': 'id, name, email',
}
```